# Select element based on EXACT text contents

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs that all contain a `p` tag classed as `index`. The textual content of these `p` tags is a number from 1 to *n* (although probably no more than maybe 30-40). I had the following selector, which worked fine in preliminary testing:

```
var ad = $('.existing_ad .index:contains('+index+')').parents('.existing_ad');
```

Where `index` is the numeric index I retrieved from the `p` tag and `.existing_ad` is the class of the parent `div`. As I said, this worked fine... until I went with higher numbers. For instance, when the index is **1**, it selects the `.existing_ad`s where the index HAS A **1** IN IT, e.g. 1, 10-19, 21, 31, etc.

**How can I get ONLY index *n*?**

Comment: Not knowing about this distinction can lead to huge problems +1

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('.existing_ad .index').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == index;
}).parents('.existing_ad');
```

Comment: ah yes. my good friend `filter()`. how often i forget about you. +1, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you use `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 29):

If you use it a lot, you could create an extension

```
$.expr[":"].containsExact = function (obj, index, meta, stack) {
  return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || $(obj).text() || "") == meta[3];
};
```

`$('div:containsExact('John')` will match `<div>John</div>` but not `<div>Johnny</div>`

For the original question, it would be

```
var ad = $(".existing_ad .index:containsExact('"+index+"')").parents('.existing_ad');
```

Comment: Yea this worked very well for me. Note that I didn't have to use quotes around FTEs in the following: `$(".table tr").find('td:first:containsExact(FTEs)').text();`

Comment: In practical applications it is sometimes useful to add a `.trim()` after the closing parenthesis before the `== meta[3];` to match regardless of whitespace before and after the exact text.

Comment: Another reason the extension works so well is that you can use it when a function like `filter()` is not appropriate and you really need a selector.  In my case, I was using a `has()` filter, so there was no obvious way to add a filter to the `has()`.  (At least, it wasn't obvious to me.) But the extension worked really well.