# Get reference to an element which has exactly a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a reference to an elment which has exactly a certain text value with jquery css selector.

Example:

```
<table >
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <i>MYVAL</i>  <!-- I want the reference to this element-->
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

But I cannot succeed in it just writing

```
$('table tbody tr td i[value="MYVAL"]').SomeFunction();
```

Which is the correct syntax?

Comment: If you're asking a jQuery question, don't title-tag it with CSS please.

Comment: The term for the text "MYVAL" is not `value`, it's `content`.  The term "value" is used for `<input>` elements (etc) that actually have a "value" attribute.

Comment: but this is aso about css selectors...

Comment: @DanieleB It's primarily a jQuery question, and you generally shouldn't include tags in the title of your questions anyway. Questions already *have* tags to specify what the question relates to.

Comment: You cannot select an element by its exact text content with either a CSS selector or a jQuery selector (not even with `:contains()`). You're going to have to check its text manually.

Comment: There is no exact text selector in jQuery due to whitespace ambiguities, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673777/select-link-by-text-exact-match for alternatives

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ok I removed the css tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE**  thats not using pure CSS selector!

Using .filter():

http://jsfiddle.net/p6fKe/

```
$('table tbody tr td i').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == "MYVAL"}).SomeFunction();
```

Comment: What's not using a pure CSS selector?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
$('table tr td i:contains("MYVAL")').SomeFunction()
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/6wjDj/

Comment: That's going to match any `<i>` element that contains `MYVAL` in its content, even if its content is not *exactly equal* to `MYVAL`. I'm not sure this will satisfy the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
function selectTextElement(text) {
    var elements = [];
    $('table tbody tr td i').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).text() == text) {
            elements.push(jQuery(this));
        }
    });
    return elements;
}
```