# JavaScript/jQuery - Get option attribute from select menu by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<select name="Pcolor" id="image" style="height:30px;">
    <option value="">Избран цвят: Blue/Lt Blue </option>
    <option value="45751303" color-number="0">Black</option>
    <option value="45751343" color-number="1">Black/Pink</option>
    <option value="45751359" color-number="2">Blue/Lt Blue</option>
    <option value="45751324" color-number="3">Dk Purple/Purpl</option>
    <option value="45751390" color-number="4">Ink/Cerise</option>
</select>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var ColorSelectt = $('#image').find('option[text="Black/Pink"]').attr("color-number");
alert(ColorSelectt);
```

All what i want to do is to find the option from select menu with id `image` that have text (not value) `Black/Pink` for example and then get the value contained in `color-number=""`.

When the alert appears it gives me response `undefined`, why is that ?

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Do you have multiple selects with the same id by any chance?

Comment: No, there is only one select menu with id `image`

Comment: use 'contains' in the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:contains` [content filter](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/content-filter-selector/) to select all elements that contain the specified text.

```js
var ColorSelectt = $('#image option:contains("Grey M/Navy")').attr("color-number");
var ColorSelectt2 = $('#image option:contains("Navy/Grey M")').attr("color-number");

alert(ColorSelectt + ':' + ColorSelectt2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Pcolor" id="image" style="height:30px;">
    <option value="">Избран цвят: Blue/Lt Blue </option>
    <option value="45751303" color-number="0">Black</option>
    <option value="45751343" color-number="1">Black/Pink</option>
    <option value="45751359" color-number="2">Blue/Lt Blue</option>
    <option value="45751324" color-number="3">Dk Purple/Purpl</option>
    <option value="45751390" color-number="4">Ink/Cerise</option>
    <option value="45751390" color-number="5">Grey M/Navy</option>
    <option value="45751390" color-number="6">Navy/Grey M</option>
    
</select>
```

Comment: This code is not working when there are similar case: If there is one option with text `Grey M/Navy` and after that another with text `Navy/Grey M`. If i target the last one i get the number from `color-number` but if i try to get the first one i get `undefined`. Can you help me about that ?

Comment: I updated the answer with your case. It works as expected. If you need exact match, take a look at this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673777/select-link-by-text-exact-match

Comment: Can you please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350022/jquery-contains-issue-when-trying-to-select-option-menu There is something very strange. Please test it with the code there. Thanks in advace. If it matters i use `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` Does it make any difference ?

Comment: Is there anyway so i can skip the first occurrence when i am searching ?

Comment: `$($('#image option:contains(text)')[1]).attr()`. jQuery returns colletion of elements you can use it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

TRy:

```
    var ColorSelectt = $('#image').find('option:contains("Black/Pink")').attr("color-number");
    alert(ColorSelectt);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cw6knsc5/

or :

```
 var ColorSelectt = $('#image option:contains("Black/Pink")').attr("color-number");
    alert(ColorSelectt);
```

Comment: Still gets `undefined`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cw6knsc5/