# jQuery - contains issue when trying to select option menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<select name="Pcolor" id="image" style="height:30px;">
   <option value="">Избран цвят: Grey M/Navy </option>
   <option value="48503341" color-number="0">Black/Charcoal</option>
   <option value="48503326" color-number="1">Charcoal M/Blk</option>
   <option value="48503325" color-number="2">Grey M/Navy</option>
   <option value="48503351" color-number="3">Navy/Grey M</option>
</select>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var TargetText = "Charcoal M/Blk";
var ColorSelectt = $('#image').find('option:contains(TargetText)').attr("color-number");
alert(ColorSelectt);
```

With the Javascript code shown i get the attribute from the select menu option, but only when i target `Grey M/Navy` i get response `undefined`. With all other cases the code works well, why ?

Can you help me out resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The matter in this question is another. As you can see i am not asking how to select the attribute id, there is another problem described in my question!!

Comment: The code I gave you in the previous question still works. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oreyuvmx/1/) as does the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below code. you need to concat `TargetText` variable using `+`

NOTE : as discuss answer is updated to skip first option in search using `:gt(0)`

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9rk99urn/3/)

```
var TargetText = "Grey M/Navy";
var ColorSelectt = $('#image').find('option:gt(0):contains("'+TargetText+'")').attr("color-number");
alert(ColorSelectt);
```

Comment: check my demo on fiddle

Comment: Don't try with `Navy/Grey M` try with `Grey M/Navy` as i said with the last one i have no problems, try with `Grey M/Navy` !!!

Comment: you used  `Grey M/Navy`  two time and first one has no data attribute  so it will give undefined <option value="">Grey M/Navy </option>

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/9rk99urn/1/    this will get first `Grey M/Navy` data attribute

Comment: Is there anyway so i can skip the first occurrence ?

Comment: use `option:gt(0):contains`