# Selecting specific links from large list

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, jquery-selectors, href

I am new to javascript/jquery:

If i have a lot of links - how can i select specific ones. For example if i have 1000 links, each consisting of hrefs and link text - and i want to select 5 specific links, what is the easiest way to do this ?

My current solution is like so:

```
var firstLink = $('.link_list a').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() === "Link One Text"; });
});
var secondLink = $('.link_list a').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() === "Link Two Text"; });
});
```

This is keeping in mind, I want to only select specific links, see [Select link by text (exact match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673777/select-link-by-text-exact-match).

This seems a bit messy to have a lot of variables defined using the same filter function over and over. Any other ideas ?

Comment: `filter` creates an array, why don't you just use one loop, check the texts in a loop (use an array of texts) and return T/F correspondingly. After that you'll have references of all the wanted links in a single array.

Answer (score 0):

turn it into a function?

```
function getLinkByText(text){
   return $('.link_list a').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).text() === text; });
   });
}

var firstLink = getLinkByText("Link One Text");
var secondLink = getLinkByText("Link Two Text");
```