# Using Contains, getting too many results

Tags: jquery, contains

I am trying to create a drop down (for a personalised chrome extension) that will take add a class to tick boxes (so they are selected) if their title matches what is in the text box (the data is a long string split by commas).

However I am trying to make it so that it only searches for the text and not more suchs as:

If I am searching for: "GDPR"

It currently finds "GDPR" and "GDPR Compliant".

I need it to show only "GDPR".

```
//adds the drop down
jQuery('body').prepend('<div style="border: 3px solid black;position: 
absolute;width: 80%;top: 10%;left: 10%;right: 10%;background-color: 
rgba(225,225,225,0.95);z-index: 1000;cursor: pointer;padding: 1%;">Input your 
options comma deliminated: <input class="options_text" style="float:right; 
padding-left:5px; width:50%;"><br/><input type="submit" 
class="options_select"></div>')

//adds class
jQuery('.options_select').click(function(){
x = jQuery('.options_text').val().split(",")
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
s = '.card_answer .content:contains('+x[i]+')'
    if(x[i] == jQuery(s).val()){
        jQuery(s).parent().parent().addClass('selectable_selected')
    }
}
}
)
```

Comment: Try providing a code that reproduces the issue and you'll have better chances to get answer here.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match the question.  How are you "using contains"?

Comment: A search on "contains exactly" finds many results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select link by text (exact match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673777/select-link-by-text-exact-match)

Comment: I tired using a filter but I couldn't get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by using split to loop through and break the results down into just what I needed.

Comment: Please, add some code to complete your answer. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer :)