# jQuery - contains() - search only full match variables

Tags: jquery, contains

Can I get using jQuery contains() only variables which is 100% matchable?
For example, I have something like that:

```
<div>Test</div>
<div>Tester</div>
```

and when I use:

```
 $('div:contains("Test")').length
```

I get two results, but I want get only result which is full matchable for string which I use inside contains() function. Is there any function similar to contains() but which get only full matchable results?

I know, I can do it in that way:

```
for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    if ( obj[i].innerText == 'Test' )
    {
        alert('Thats it! obj[i]');
    }
}
```

But problem is when I want to check if that searched div is visible. When I use:

```
obj[1].is(':visible');
```

I got:

`TypeError: $(...)[1].is is not a function`

But when I use:

```
 obj.is(':visible')
```

I got:

```
true
```

That's problem for me, because I need to check only div which contains: "Test" only.

Is it possible to search only full matchable results?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673777/select-link-by-text-exact-match).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an "exact match" selector in jQuery. A compact way to express this is with `filter`:

```
$('div').filter(function() {return $(this).text() === 'Test';}).is(':visible')
```