# Update HTML container text on text match using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change text on products that are out of stock. This is what I have so far:

```js
$( ".box.stock:contains('0 Stock')" ).text('Temporarily out of stock. Call to order. ').addClass( "Lager" );
```

This works, but it also works on all products with a zero in it. How do I change it to just stock status with "0" in it?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338439/select-element-based-on-exact-text-contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do that with contains. You would need to use filter

```
$(".box.stock").filter( function() {  
    return $(this).text() === "0 Stock";
}).text('Temporarily out of stock. Call to order. ').addClass( "Lager" )
```