# select2 - removing a js inserted item keeps it as an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i have a standard select2 setup

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cities">Enter Cities</label>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control cities-tags" multiple="multiple"></select>
    
        <button type="button" id="import-cities" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#importModal">
        <svg>...</svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

apply select 2

```
$(".cities-tags").select2({
    tags: true,
})
```

i also have a model to paste a comma separated values as text, and it will split them into separate tags and input them.

```
// #importCitiesBtn is a button in the model to confirm pasting
$('#importCitiesBtn').on('click', function() {
    var importedCities = $('#importCitiesInput').val().split(',');

    importedCities.forEach(function(cityName) {
        if (cityName.trim() == '') {
            return;
        }
        let option = $('.cities-tags').find("option:contains('" + cityName.trim() + "')");

        if (option.length === 0) {
            var newOption = new Option(cityName.trim(), cityName.trim(), true, true);        
            $('.cities-tags').append(newOption).trigger('change');
        } else {
               $('.cities-tags').val(cityName.trim()).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

the js insertion works fine, here is the problem:

when i insert cities manually and remove them(click the x), they are completely removed (good)

when i remove a js inserted item, its removed from the selected items but an option is still present (bad)

expected behavior: when i remove an item wither added manually or by js, it has no trace or its option is also removed from the list.

[add logic source](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

note: extra points if you can write logic to paste the comma separated string directly into the select and have it automatically parse and append.

Comment: Slightly off topic: `.find("option:contains('"` will find options that... well... *contain* the text, eg if you try to import "York" but already have "New York" it will select New York

Comment: ok, i understand the confusion, i only remove selected items by clicking the [x], i dont deselect with js, but creating a new option manually, and removing it, removes its selection and its option from the list, unlike adding with js, when adding with js then removing with the [x] its selection is removed but its option remains.

Comment: *but creating a new option manually, and removing it, removes its selection and its option* - yes, this helps clarify.    TBH I didn't know it did this.   Here's a test page that shows it does add underlying `option` elements.  I've not dug through the select2 code...      https://jsfiddle.net/xzkcmfhp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> creating a new option manually, and removing it, removes its selection and its option

Given a `<select multiple>` and `$(..).select({ tags: true })` the select2 allows you to *type* new entries.  Removing these entries from the selected tags also removes them from the `<select>` options.

When select2 does this, it adds an additional attribute: `data-select2-tag='true'` - this is how it knows to delete the `option` when you unselect the tag.

So, when adding via code, you can just add that same attribute and it will be auto-removed - it must be an attribute, using `$(..).data(` will not suffice.

As you're using jQuery and without changing the rest of the code, this becomes:

```
var newOption = new Option(text, value, true, true);
$(newOption).attr("data-select2-tag", "true");
```

Example that adds new options and then (auto-)removes them when you unselect the tag:

```js
$('.states').select2({
  tags: true
});

$("#add").click(() => {
  let opt = $(".states option").length;
  var newOption = new Option("opt " + opt, opt, true, true);
  $(newOption).attr("data-select2-tag", "true");
  $('.states').append(newOption).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="states" multiple>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>

<br/>

<button id="add">
click to add new entry with code
</button>
```

---

> logic to paste the comma separated string directly into the select and have it automatically parse and append

You can listen for the `select2:selecting` event (note: different versions of [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) use different events), then check `e.params.args.data.text` - if this has a comma, then split and add multiple new options.

If an option already exists then need to *update* the value to include the existing option (rather than replace the value completely which is what the select2 site provides (as per the code in the question))

Updated snippet:  **NB: This is not working 100%** included here as a starter point.  It seems to lose when items are added with data-select2-tag when entering comma separated values that include existing options.

```js
// Add an exact-equals (can also make this case insensitive)
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/16158932/2181514
$.expr[":"].equals = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
  return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || $(obj).text() || "") == meta[3];
};

$('.states').select2({
  tags: true
});

$("#countBtn").click(() => {
  console.log($(".states option").length)
});

$("#addBtn").click(() => {
  let opt = $(".states option").length;
  // this would normally need a check for duplicate, left out here for simplicity
  var newOption = new Option("opt " + opt, opt, true, true);
  $(newOption).data("select2-tag", "true");
  $('.states').append(newOption).trigger('change');
});

$(".states").on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
  if (e.params.args.data.element) return;

  let ddl = $(this);

  let entry = e.params.args.data;
  var opts = entry.text.split(",");

  // only process if more than one, if just one new entry, allow select2 to do its own thing
  if (opts.length > 1) {

    for (var opt of opts) {

      // Check for existing
      let option = ddl.find("option:equals('" + opt.trim() + "')");

      if (option.length === 0) {
        // This specific opt is new
        let newOption = new Option(opt.trim(), opt.trim(), true, true);
        $(newOption).data("select2-tag", "true");
        ddl.append(newOption).trigger('change');
      } else {
        // This opt already exists so update the array of selected values
        // NB: This then *removes* the select2-tag
        let val = ddl.val();
        val.push(opt.trim());
        ddl.val(val).trigger('change');
      }

      // set the return to the current loop, so returns the last entry to select2
      // otherwise it tries to add the original comma-separated list
      e.params.args.data.text = opt.trim();
      e.params.args.data.id = opt.trim();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="states" multiple>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <!-- options that are quicker to type, for testing -->
  <option value="X">X</option>
  <option value="Y">Y</option>
</select>

<button id="countBtn">
click after typing new entry
</button>

<button id="addBtn">
click to add new entry with code
</button>
```

Comment: works like a charm, did you have to go through the docs and find this or did you find it on your own? because it certainly, it should be included in the docs.

Comment: I used that test fiddle: added a new item by typing in the box, then browser inspect to see what the new `<option>` looked like.  Then tried to replicate it through code and found that it worked.